# why $m_p = (M_p)_f$ for the restriction $r_U : \mathcal{O}(X) \to \mathcal{O}(U)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X\subset \Bbb{A}^n$ be the affine variety, consider the principle neiborhood $p \in U = D(f)$ for some nonconstant, irreducible polynomial, it's again a affine variety, there is a morphism inject into:

$$i : D(f) \to X$$

which induces a map on the set of regular function:
$$i^* : \mathcal{O}(X) \to \mathcal{O}(D(f))\\f \mapsto f\circ i$$

If we denote the ideals $M_p =\{g\in \mathcal{O}(X)\mid g(p) = 0\}$ and $m_p = \{g\in \mathcal{O}(U)\mid g(p) = 0\}$ then easy to check $i^*(M_p) \subset m_p$.

Consider the localization at the principle ideal $(f)$ , prove that $(M_p)_f \cong m_p$.

Comment: This is just [your last question again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496475/stalk-is-identified-with-the-localization-of-the-coordinate-ring-for-irreducible).

Comment: thank you I will try to figure it out @KReiser

Comment: See Hartshorne II.2.2

Comment: haha i didn't realize this is the question that i asked before and appears in the same propersition  in Hartshorne